# How to append to a list in a file with json?

Tags: python

I am working on creating a login system in python.
if LoginOrRegister == "create":

```
Username = input("Please enter a Username:")
EmailAddress = input("Please enter an Email Adress:")
Password = input("Please set your Password:")

Userdata = {"Username": Username,
 "EmailAddress": EmailAddress,
 "Password": Password
 }

with open("Database.txt", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
data["User"].append(Userdata)
with open("Database.txt", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

To store the Userdata Information, I would like to append it to a list in a file that looks like that:
{User : []

}
But the last block throws a lot of errors. How can I append the Userdata as a dictionary to the list in my file? Is Json maybe not the right module to use? Thanks in advance!

Here are the Errors:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/kosti/Desktop/Python/LernProjekte/Test.py", line 17, in 
data = json.load(f)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\json_*init*_.py", line 296, in load
parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\json_*init*_.py", line 348, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: What are the errors…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your file is a txt file not JSON

secondly the file shouldn't be empty, or
json.load()
will raise an Error so try this, so keep in mind the first time you do this comment out the reading part

```
with open('DataBase.json', 'r') as f:
    Data = json.load(f)

Data['User'].append(UserData)
with open("DataBase.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(Data, f)
```

Edit :

Your files are configured the wrong way so instead of doing this

```
{
  "User" : 
   []
 }
```

Do this

```
{ 'User' : [] }
```

as you can see there are no empty lines so it will not produce an error, *unlike the one on top* because
json.load(f)
Read lines one by one so I suspect there's an empty line in file somewhere

Comment: Thank you! I would have run into these problems sooner or later, but the errors are still occuring. There are the same as in the (now edited) post, I think.

Comment: @Torax I see you have put the file in the wrong way see the answer as I will edit it

Answer (score 0):

This does the work. don't forget to accept it as answer

```
if LoginOrRegister == "create":
    Username = input("Please enter a Username:")
    EmailAddress = input("Please enter an Email Adress:")
    Password = input("Please set your Password:")

    Userdata = {"Username": Username,
    "EmailAddress": EmailAddress,
    "Password": Password
    }

    with open("Database.json", "r+") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    data["User"].append(Userdata)
    with open("Database.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(data, f)
```